# Fastest way to sort object's array based on other's object's array property

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I've got two objects arrays and both of them have columnId property. 
I want to make the order of the first object's array same as the order of the second.

I've tried this:

```
filtered = visibleColumns.filter(function(v) {
            return filtered.includes(v.colId);
        });
```

where `filtered` is my result array and `visibleColumns` is array which order I need, but it doesn't work.

example of arrays:

```js
filtered = [{
  colId:1,
  title: 'col1',
  size: 10
},
{
  colId:2,
  title: 'col2',
  size: 10
}];

visibleColumns = [{
  colId:2,
  visible: true
  },
{
  colId:1,
  visible: true
}];
```

Comment: `.filter` wouldn't make the *order* of the elements different. You need `.sort`

Comment: Also, you are trying to filter based on the array you are *going to get* - the `visibleColumns.filter()`  result is assigned to `filtered` and you also use `filtered.includes` inside the predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an object with the wanted order and take a default value for unknown id for sorting them to bottom.

```js
var filtered = [{ colId: 1, title: 'col1', size: 10 }, { colId: 2, title: 'col2', size: 10 }],
    visibleColumns = [{ colId: 2, visible: true }, { colId: 1, visible: true }],
    order = visibleColumns.reduce((o, { colId }, i) => (o[colId] = i + 1, o), {});

filtered.sort((a, b) => (order[a.colId] || Infinity) - (order[b.colId] || Infinity));

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: noob question, but what does ` Infinity` do? I never used it before

Comment: it is a symbolic constant of a numerical value of infinity. in combination with the order of known id, which return a value of 1, ..., n, you could move unknown id to the bottom, of if using a negative value, to top.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object which maps each `colId` from `visibleColumns` to it's index in the array. Get the index for each `colId` while sorting `filtered`

```js
const filtered = [{ colId: 1, title: "col1", size: 10 }, { colId: 2, title: "col2", size: 10 }],
      visibleColumns = [{ colId: 2, visible: true }, { colId: 1, visible: true }];

const order = new Map(visibleColumns.map((o, i) => [o.colId, i]))

filtered.sort((a, b) => order.get(a.colId) - order.get(b.colId))

console.log(filtered)
```